# Should recursive function call terminate or is its implementation faulty?

Tags: haskell

I'm working my way through *Haskell Programming From First Principles* and am stuck proving that I've correctly answered question 1 of the *Finally something other than a list* exercise subsection. The following function invocation doesn't terminate and I can't tell if that's expected or if my implementation is faulty.

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf 
                  | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a) 
                    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

unfold :: (a -> Maybe (a, b, a)) -> a -> BinaryTree b
unfold func seed = 
  case (func seed) of
    Just (l, m, r) -> Node (unfold func l) m (unfold func r)
    Nothing -> Leaf
```

I would *think* that each `a`/`x` would eventually be decremented/incremented until it causes the `if` to take the `True` branch and return a `Nothing`/`Leaf`.

```
func = (\x -> if (x < 0 || x > 10) 
                then Nothing  
                else Just (x - 1, x, x + 1))
unfold func 5
-- Node (Node (Node (Node (Node (Node Leaf 0 ... ad infinitum
```

Comment: Nice example. The issue is that you can take the left branch, then the right one, then left, then right, forever, and so you have `5-1+1-1+1....` which never falls outside the interval, so it generates an infinitely deep tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation generates infinitely many calls to `unfold`.

Consider the first recursive call, where your initial seed value of `5` is split into `4` and `6` for the left and right subtree. There you split this new seed into `3` and `5` on the left and `5` and `7` on the right, hence you define an infinitely large tree.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. I now see that 1) this function is behaving as expected and 2) why that is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the program never terminates can be understood if you try to invoke `func` outside `unfold`. Here, I renamed `func` to `unfolder`, because the Haskell linter didn't like that it had the same name as the `func` argument.

Close to the boundaries, `unfolder` returns these values:

```
*So> unfolder 1
Just (0,1,2)
*So> unfolder 0
Just (-1,0,1)
*So> unfolder (-1)
Nothing
```

For `unfolder 0`, the *left* branch clearly evaluates to `Nothing` the next time around, but the *right* branch is `unfolder 1`, which evaluates to `Just (0,1,2)`, and so on ad infinitum.

Comment: I wish I could select both answers, but I chose mschmidt's because it was submitted first.